# REACTJS: value is not defined

Tags: reactjs

I have three states which consists of name, age and email which its values are manually specficied in order to display the values in the three input text fields.

However, I want to make all of the three values from the input text field editable as well.

I'm receving an error `age is not defined`. May I know why?

Here is the link which used to run the code below:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zyeeed

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

class Info extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    state = {
      name = "Jack Sparrow",
      age = "52",
      email = "jacksparrow52@gmail.com"
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    let newState = {...this.state};
      newState[e.target.name] = e.target.name
    this.setState({
      newState
    })
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.name} placeholder="Enter your name..." onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} />
        <br /> <br />
        <input type="text" name="age" value={this.state.age} placeholder="Enter your age..." onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} />
        <br /> <br />
        <input type="text" name="email" value={this.state.email} placeholder="Enter your email..." onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} />
        <h3>Output states:</h3>
        <p id="name">Entered Name: {this.state.name}</p>
        <p id="age">Entered Age: {this.state.age}</p>
        <p id="age">Entered Email: {this.state.email}</p>
      </div>

    );
  }
}

render(<Info />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few things missing.

1. Need to use `this.state`
2. Correct the assignment of state properties
3. Change `newState[e.target.name] = e.target.name` to `newState[e.target.name] = e.target.value`
4. Change `this.setState({ newState })` to `this.setState(newState)` or `this.setState({ ...newState })`

I think that covers it.  I made a working [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-bohr-7epcc?file=/src/App.js).  Hope that helps!

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the speedy reply! I sincerely appreciate your help.. I'm sorry but I have another question. I want to make the input field editable as well but I'm not sure how do it. Is there any major changes to the code that I have to do?

Comment: Did you see the example?  The inputs are editable in the example.  It is essentially a copy of your code with the fixes I mentioned.  Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

Missing a `this`

```
this.state = {
    name = "Jack Sparrow",
    age = "52",
    email = "jacksparrow52@gmail.com"
};
```